# Python: sub string search

Tags: python, string, search

I am trying to search for whole words with in a string and not sure how to do it.

```
str1 = 'this is'
str2 ='I think this isnt right'
str1 in str2
```

gives me `True`, but I want it to return `False`. How do I do this? Thank you.

I tried `str2.find(str1), re.search(str1,str2),` but I am not getting them to return nothing or a False.

Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `\b` entity in regular expressions to match word boundaries.

```
re.search(r'\bthis is\b', 'I think this isnt right')
```

Comment: ok. Thanks. how do I generalize this using word1 = 'this is' and line1 = 'I think this isnt right'?

Comment: Er, same way as you generalize anything else: by using variables. What are you having problems with?

Comment: I have str1 = 'this is' and str2 = 'i think this isnt right'. my syntax isnt working. re.search(str1,str2). It gives the object position. How do I make is return nothing? thanks.

Comment: @Pradeep: Notice the `\b` at the beginning and ending of `r'\bthis is\b'`.  Those are word boundaries.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, Yes, I understand. how do I pass variable instead of 'this is'? Thanks.

Comment: @Pradeep:  Really?  `re.search(r'\b%s\b' % str1, str2)`

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) without a regular expression:

```
set(['this', 'is']).issubset(set('I think this isnt right'.split(' ')))
```

If the string is really long or you're going to keep evaluating if words are in the set, this could be more efficient. For example:

```
>>> words = set('I think this isnt right'.split(' '))
>>> words
set(['I', 'this', 'isnt', 'right', 'think'])
>>> 'this' in words
True
>>> 'is' in words
False
```

Comment: I believe Pradeep would want this to return false: `set(['this', 'is']).issubset(set('I think this thing is wrong'.split(' ')))`.